# What shape should toilet seats be?

Tags: physical

This is something which has been annoying me for a while now. It seems a simple question: what shape of toilet seat is nicer for the user?

However, I've asked around a bit and there's quite a lot of different shapes and opinions to go with them. The two main shapes seem to be rounded and elongated (circle and oval), like this:

[image: Toilet seat shapes]

There are about equal numbers of people preferring each, so I can't really tell what's better. It'd be good to see some studies if you can, but otherwise - what shape is better for the user?

Comment: Opinions and thoughts don't fit in se format, studies are definitely much better !

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry to say, but this place is for definitive answers as apposed to things that could spark opinionated arguments.

Comment: @Majed - Badly worded - this isn't supposed to spark opinionated arguments. Edited.

Comment: Who is your audience? What about squat toilets? I know there is a widely populated part of the world that uses them!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my two cents but I would bet that the answer is completely situational due to the fact that there are varying anatomical structures amongst humans (gasp!)

Certain shapes and sizes are better suited for certain butts, period. Wide hips, big butts, flat butts, narrows butts, etc...

If you are finding a trend for elongated-extended in your area then scope out the physical demographic of people in your area and you should be able to draw some conclusions as to why toilet seats of that shape are more prevalent in your area/city/region/country/etc.

If a certain style is comfortable then you can bet your last dollar that I will be buying it!

Comment: There is more to it than the physical demographic: there is 'fashion'.  Which is why square toilet seats exist: http://www.victorianplumbing.co.uk/Bliss-Squared-Soft-Close-Toilet-Seat-NCH198.aspx?

Comment: @PhillipW the question asks "what shape of toilet seat is nicer for the user?" and fashion is called fashion because it comes and goes without any purpose. Yes, certain people will follow it because they don't know how to think for themselves but just because it's popularity rose due to fashion does not equate to a nicer experience for the user. Are you one of the purchasers of this square toilet seat? If so then is it nice to use?

Comment: I'd argue that the aesthetic experience of a product IS part of the user experience, and that there is more to 'nicer to use' than pure ergonomics.